# My Ubuntu 14.04 Wifi not working Toshiba L650 tried everything

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 09 Mar 2015 18:16 IST +0530

Booted last: 09 Mar 2015 18:07 IST +0530

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. Device [144f:7175]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet [1969:2060] (rev c1)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:fd50]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0930:0214 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b1d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd CNF9055 Toshiba Webcam
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

brcmsmac              563041  0 
cordic                 12574  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               15618  1 brcmsmac
b43                   387371  0 
mac80211              630669  2 b43,brcmsmac
cfg80211              484040  3 b43,brcmsmac,mac80211
ssb                    62379  1 b43
bcma                   52096  3 b43,brcmsmac
wmi                    19177  1 toshiba_acpi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          inet addr:10.208.17.214  Bcast:10.208.17.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ca0a:a9ff:fec6:7da4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2789 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2053 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2627176 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:238415 (238.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.208.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.208.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.1
search pune.cdac.in

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            atl1c
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.208.17.214
    Prefix:          23 (255.255.254.0)
    Gateway:         10.208.16.1

    DNS:             10.208.0.11
    DNS:             10.208.0.12

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            brcmsmac
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    Ldap:            Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WPA2 Enterprise
    Vayudoot-Teachers: Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 35 WPA2 Enterprise
    SKY NET:         Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 WPA2 Enterprise
    Vayudoot-Administrative: Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 WPA2 Enterprise
    Vayudoot-Administrative: Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 35 WPA2 Enterprise
    Ldap:            Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 WPA2 Enterprise
    VAYUDOOT:        Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WPA2 Enterprise
    SKY NET:         Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 35 WPA2 Enterprise
    CNC_NEW_NETWORK: Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA2
    CNC_NEW_NETWORK: Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 29 WPA2
    Vayudoot-Students: Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WPA2 Enterprise
    Vayudoot-Guest:  Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 29 WPA2 Enterprise
    Vayudoot-Guest:  Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WPA2 Enterprise
    Vayudoot-Teachers: Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 29 WPA2 Enterprise
    Vayudoot-Students: Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WPA2 Enterprise
    VAYUDOOT:        Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 WPA2 Enterprise
    Vayudoot-Administrative: Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 22 WPA2 Enterprise
    VAYUDOOT:        Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA2 Enterprise
    CDAC:            Infra, , Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 35
    CNC_NEW_NETWORK: Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA2
    CDAC:            Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40
    Vayudoot-Students: Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA2 Enterprise
    SKY NET:         Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 19 WPA2 Enterprise

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CDAC]] (600 root)
[connection] id=CDAC | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=CDAC | mac-address=
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CNC_NEW_NETWORK]] (600 root)
[connection] id=CNC_NEW_NETWORK | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=CNC_NEW_NETWORK | mac-address=
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country US:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 27)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 17)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5490 - 5600 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5650 - 5710 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 30)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

Channel occupancy:

      6   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      8   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"CDAC"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001acf35873af
                    Extra: Last beacon: 32ms ago
          Cell 02 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=41/70  Signal level=-69 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"CDAC"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000e3f2bf2c2c
                    Extra: Last beacon: 32ms ago
          Cell 03 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"SKY NET"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000014f9481178
                    Extra: Last beacon: 624ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 04 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"VAYUDOOT"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000014f949a977
                    Extra: Last beacon: 592ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 05 - Address: 
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Vayudoot-Administrative"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000002a1f9ae978
                    Extra: Last beacon: 156ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 06 - Address: 
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"CNC_NEW_NETWORK"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000002a1f9c8bc8
                    Extra: Last beacon: 36ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 07 - Address: 
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=34/70  Signal level=-76 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"SKY NET"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000002a1f9ae978
                    Extra: Last beacon: 120ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 08 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Vayudoot-Teachers"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000014f949a977
                    Extra: Last beacon: 612ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 09 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Vayudoot-Students"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000014f949a977
                    Extra: Last beacon: 580ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 10 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ldap"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000014f949a977
                    Extra: Last beacon: 568ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 11 - Address: 
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Vayudoot-Students"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000002a1f9ae977
                    Extra: Last beacon: 76ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 12 - Address: 
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ldap"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000002a1f9ce0d9
                    Extra: Last beacon: 32ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 13 - Address: 
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=31/70  Signal level=-79 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Vayudoot-Teachers"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000002a1f9ae978
                    Extra: Last beacon: 108ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 14 - Address: 
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=21/70  Signal level=-89 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Vayudoot-Teachers"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000014f9be01e6
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 15 - Address: 
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"VAYUDOOT"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000002a1f9b848c
                    Extra: Last beacon: 32ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported

##### module infos ######################

[brcmsmac]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmsmac/brcmsmac.ko
firmware:       brcm/bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw
firmware:       brcm/bcm43xx-0.fw
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11n wireless LAN driver.
author:         Broadcom Corporation
srcversion:     8A64A0EA2502AA6E237B856
depends:        bcma,mac80211,brcmutil,cfg80211,cordic
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        34:99:21:39:F3:DA:40:B6:20:BD:55:17:59:7B:A8:5A:F5:79:7C:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[brcmutil]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmutil/brcmutil.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11n wireless LAN driver utilities.
author:         Broadcom Corporation
srcversion:     E81EE4CBB6A7A689150D93D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        34:99:21:39:F3:DA:40:B6:20:BD:55:17:59:7B:A8:5A:F5:79:7C:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[b43]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
srcversion:     7ABBDDCA84C087640B27AE6
depends:        bcma,ssb,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        34:99:21:39:F3:DA:40:B6:20:BD:55:17:59:7B:A8:5A:F5:79:7C:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)
parm:           allhwsupport:Enable support for all hardware (even it if overlaps with the brcmsmac driver) (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     385697223F8285F67C93A06
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        34:99:21:39:F3:DA:40:B6:20:BD:55:17:59:7B:A8:5A:F5:79:7C:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     C2478077E22138832B71659
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        34:99:21:39:F3:DA:40:B6:20:BD:55:17:59:7B:A8:5A:F5:79:7C:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[ssb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     3DE188310F77C566C2E8CB3
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        34:99:21:39:F3:DA:40:B6:20:BD:55:17:59:7B:A8:5A:F5:79:7C:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     E41B811D88783DD5BC38565
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        34:99:21:39:F3:DA:40:B6:20:BD:55:17:59:7B:A8:5A:F5:79:7C:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### module parameters #################

[b43]
allhwsupport: 0
bad_frames_preempt: 0
btcoex: 1
hwpctl: 0
hwtkip: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
pio: 0
qos: 1
verbose: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc
b43

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x1969:0x2060 (atl1c)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4727 (brcmsmac)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   19.210007] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[   19.210061] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[   19.210251] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   50.709566] wlan0: authenticate with 
[   50.712465] wlan0: send auth to  (try 1/3)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: You might want to look into some log files when you try to start the WiFi. `tail -f /var/log/{daemons.log,syslog,messages,dmesg.log}`  How do you try to start it?  Have you set it up with WindowManager? If you look into dmesg.log, do you see some complainings of firmware?  You might need to install the packager `firmware-linux-nonfree`.  That is usually the problem with these `Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter`.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
echo "blacklist b43" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot and wifi should be working.